# Check Object type in List of Objects

Tags: c#, wpf, list, types

Got a WPF Form with a StackPanel containing Expanders with StackPanels in it.

```
<Expander Name="eSoftware" Header="5 Software">
    <StackPanel Name="StSoftware" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="0,0,8,0">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,10" Width="29">
            <Image x:Name="img" Height="26" Source="Images/3453120.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel  Margin="0,10">
            <Label  x:Name="lbl" Content="Label"  Margin="0,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Expander>
```

I read the Content of the Expander in a list of Objects.
Now i must know if the list contains an object of type stackpanel.

```
List<Object> tmpList = new List<Object>();
tmpList = ReadChild((StackPanel)exp.Content)  //gives out the content of an expander. In the Upper case it is 2 StackPanels

if(tmpList.Contains.typeof(StackPanel)=true) //that's wrong
{
  //search for the Stackpanel with lables in it
}
```

Comment: You probably want to compare instead of assignment: `tmpList.Contains.typeof(StackPanel)=true`     to `tmpList.Contains.typeof(StackPanel)==true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OfType<>` to filter for just a specific type in a list. I understand that you want to loop through all the StackPanels (in the list), so you can do something like this:

```
foreach(var panel in tmpList.OfType<StackPanel>()){
    //your work here ...
}
```

If you want to check if there is any StackPanel, then use this:

```
if(tmpList.OfType<StackPanel>().Any()){
    //...
}
```

Comment: @Shadow that's what I understand about what you wanted but if so you can see my edit for a better code.

Comment: @Shadow `OfType<>` is very useful in this case, you can do it much simpler by `tmpList.OfType<StackPanel>().Any()`

Comment: Yes. i change it. it is better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand You correctly you can use this LINQ Expression

```
var w = tmpList.Where(x=>x.IsTypeOf(StackPanel)).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this: use the `Enumerable.OfType<>()`

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx

```
foreach(var stackpanel in tmpList.OfType<StackPanel>())
{
    // search for the label. (the same trick)
    var myLabel = stackpanel.Children.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault();

    // if the label can't be found, continue to the next one.
    if(myLabel == null)
        continue;

    myLabel.Content = "whatever";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not many questions answer this part of the question.
"Now i must know if the list contains an object of type stackpanel."
Which can be achieved through the following:

```
if (tmpList.Any(x=>x.IsTypeOf(StackPanel)))
{
     //returns true if there are any stack panels in the list 
}
```

Comment: Has to be. if (objList.Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(StackPanel))) But it helps a lot. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

```
public int ExecuteDMLStatements(string query, string connection, List<string> paramNames, List<object> paramValues)
{
    int count = 0;
    try
    {
        if (paramNames.Count == paramValues.Count)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnecton(connection);
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.Count; i++)
                {
                    Type valueType = paramValues[i].GetType();
                    switch (valueType.Name)
                    {
                        case "Int32":
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramNames[i], Convert.ToInt32(paramValues[i]));
                            break;
                        case "Double":
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramNames[i], Convert.ToDouble(paramValues[i]));
                            break;
                        case "DateTime":
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramNames[i], Convert.ToDateTime(paramValues[i]));
                            break;
                        case "Single":
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramNames[i], Convert.ToString(paramValues[i]));
                            break;
                        default:
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramNames[i], Convert.ToString(paramValues[i]));
                            break;
                    }
                }
                count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Issue in ExecuteDMLStatements method.", ex);
    }
}
```